# NodeJS API Testing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, server

I have made a local express `API` using `express & nodejs`.This is my `index.js` file with all the express server:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Database models
const Panch = require('./models/panchayat');


// Starting the app
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Connect to the db
(async() => {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/village", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
})();

app.post("/api/fetchPanch/", (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body)
        // let result = Panch.find({
        //     "_id": _id
        // })
        // res.json(result);
});

app.listen(PORT, async() => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on https://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

This is the file in which I am testing the API:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.post('https://localhost:3000/api/fetchPanch', {
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'id': '5fd8eac45f2d508574c57fd5'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

But I am getting this response in the terminal;:

```sh
node:internal/process/promises:227
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

<ref *1> Error: write EPROTO 4569554368:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:96:16) {
  errno: -100,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write',
  config: {
    url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/fetchPanch',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},"id":"5fd8eac45f2d508574c57fd5"}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0',
      'Content-Length': 79
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: <ref *4> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: '/api/fetchPanch',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0',
        'Content-Length': 79
      },
      agent: undefined,
      agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      nativeProtocols: {
        'http:': {
          _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
          METHODS: [
            'ACL',        'BIND',        'CHECKOUT',
            'CONNECT',    'COPY',        'DELETE',
            'GET',        'HEAD',        'LINK',
            'LOCK',       'M-SEARCH',    'MERGE',
            'MKACTIVITY', 'MKCALENDAR',  'MKCOL',
            'MOVE',       'NOTIFY',      'OPTIONS',
            'PATCH',      'POST',        'PRI',
            'PROPFIND',   'PROPPATCH',   'PURGE',
            'PUT',        'REBIND',      'REPORT',
            'SEARCH',     'SOURCE',      'SUBSCRIBE',
            'TRACE',      'UNBIND',      'UNLINK',
            'UNLOCK',     'UNSUBSCRIBE'
          ],
          STATUS_CODES: {
            '100': 'Continue',
            '101': 'Switching Protocols',
            '102': 'Processing',
            '103': 'Early Hints',
            '200': 'OK',
            '201': 'Created',
            '202': 'Accepted',
            '203': 'Non-Authoritative Information',
            '204': 'No Content',
            '205': 'Reset Content',
            '206': 'Partial Content',
            '207': 'Multi-Status',
            '208': 'Already Reported',
            '226': 'IM Used',
            '300': 'Multiple Choices',
            '301': 'Moved Permanently',
            '302': 'Found',
            '303': 'See Other',
            '304': 'Not Modified',
            '305': 'Use Proxy',
            '307': 'Temporary Redirect',
            '308': 'Permanent Redirect',
            '400': 'Bad Request',
            '401': 'Unauthorized',
            '402': 'Payment Required',
            '403': 'Forbidden',
            '404': 'Not Found',
            '405': 'Method Not Allowed',
            '406': 'Not Acceptable',
            '407': 'Proxy Authentication Required',
            '408': 'Request Timeout',
            '409': 'Conflict',
            '410': 'Gone',
            '411': 'Length Required',
            '412': 'Precondition Failed',
            '413': 'Payload Too Large',
            '414': 'URI Too Long',
            '415': 'Unsupported Media Type',
            '416': 'Range Not Satisfiable',
            '417': 'Expectation Failed',
            '418': "I'm a Teapot",
            '421': 'Misdirected Request',
            '422': 'Unprocessable Entity',
            '423': 'Locked',
            '424': 'Failed Dependency',
            '425': 'Too Early',
            '426': 'Upgrade Required',
            '428': 'Precondition Required',
            '429': 'Too Many Requests',
            '431': 'Request Header Fields Too Large',
            '451': 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons',
            '500': 'Internal Server Error',
            '501': 'Not Implemented',
            '502': 'Bad Gateway',
            '503': 'Service Unavailable',
            '504': 'Gateway Timeout',
            '505': 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
            '506': 'Variant Also Negotiates',
            '507': 'Insufficient Storage',
            '508': 'Loop Detected',
            '509': 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
            '510': 'Not Extended',
            '511': 'Network Authentication Required'
          },
          Agent: [Function: Agent] { defaultMaxSockets: Infinity },
          ClientRequest: [Function: ClientRequest],
          IncomingMessage: [Function: IncomingMessage],
          OutgoingMessage: [Function: OutgoingMessage],
          Server: [Function: Server],
          ServerResponse: [Function: ServerResponse],
          createServer: [Function: createServer],
          validateHeaderName: [Function: hidden],
          validateHeaderValue: [Function: hidden],
          get: [Function: get],
          request: [Function: request],
          maxHeaderSize: [Getter],
          globalAgent: [Getter/Setter]
        },
        'https:': {
          Agent: [Function: Agent],
          globalAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object],
            requests: {},
            sockets: [Object],
            freeSockets: {},
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: false,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'fifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 1,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          Server: [Function: Server],
          createServer: [Function: createServer],
          get: [Function: get],
          request: [Function: request]
        }
      },
      pathname: '/api/fetchPanch'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 79,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [
      {
        data: Buffer(79) [Uint8Array] [
          123,  34, 104, 101,  97, 100, 101, 114, 115,  34,  58, 123,
           34,  65,  99,  99, 101, 115, 115,  45,  67, 111, 110, 116,
          114, 111, 108,  45,  65, 108, 108, 111, 119,  45,  79, 114,
          105, 103, 105, 110,  34,  58,  34,  42,  34, 125,  44,  34,
          105, 100,  34,  58,  34,  53, 102, 100,  56, 101,  97,  99,
           52,  53, 102,  50, 100,  53,  48,  56,  53,  55,  52,  99,
           53,  55, 102, 100,  53,  34, 125
        ],
        encoding: undefined
      }
    ],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: <ref *2> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
          listener: [Function (anonymous)]
        },
        socket: [Function (anonymous)],
        abort: [Function (anonymous)],
        aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
        connect: [Function (anonymous)],
        error: [Function (anonymous)],
        timeout: [Function (anonymous)]
      },
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [
        {
          data: '',
          encoding: 'latin1',
          callback: [Function: bound onFinish]
        }
      ],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: <ref *3> TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: {
          allowHalfOpen: undefined,
          pipe: false,
          secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {}, singleUse: true },
          isServer: false,
          requestCert: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          session: undefined,
          ALPNProtocols: undefined,
          requestOCSP: undefined,
          enableTrace: undefined,
          pskCallback: undefined,
          highWaterMark: undefined,
          onread: undefined
        },
        _secureEstablished: false,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        secureConnecting: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        alpnProtocol: null,
        authorized: false,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          close: [
            [Function: onSocketCloseDestroySSL],
            [Function],
            [Function: onClose],
            [Function: socketCloseListener]
          ],
          end: [ [Function: onConnectEnd], [Function: onReadableStreamEnd] ],
          newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
          secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
          session: [Function (anonymous)],
          free: [Function: onFree],
          timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
          agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
          error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
          drain: [Function: ondrain]
        },
        _eventsCount: 10,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: true,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: false,
          endEmitted: false,
          reading: true,
          constructed: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: true,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: true,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: true,
          errored: [Circular *1],
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: false,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: false,
          ended: false,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: true,
          decodeStrings: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: false,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 0,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: true,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: [Circular *1],
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
        [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *3],
            [Symbol(handle_onclose)]: [Function: done]
          },
          _parentWrap: undefined,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {}, singleUse: true },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: {},
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *3]
        },
        [Symbol(verified)]: false,
        [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 7,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 288,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 288,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
          checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
          minDHSize: 1024,
          maxRedirects: 21,
          maxBodyLength: 10485760,
          protocol: 'https:',
          path: null,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0',
            'Content-Length': 79
          },
          agent: undefined,
          agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
          auth: undefined,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          port: '3000',
          nativeProtocols: { 'http:': [Object], 'https:': [Object] },
          pathname: '/api/fetchPanch',
          _defaultAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object],
            requests: {},
            sockets: [Object],
            freeSockets: {},
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: false,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'fifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 1,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          host: 'localhost',
          servername: 'localhost',
          _agentKey: 'localhost:3000::::::::::::::::::',
          encoding: null,
          singleUse: true
        }
      },
      _header: 'POST /api/fetchPanch HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.0\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 79\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: Agent {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          free: [Function (anonymous)],
          newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: { path: null },
        requests: {},
        sockets: { 'localhost:3000::::::::::::::::::': [ [TLSSocket] ] },
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        scheduling: 'fifo',
        maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
        totalSocketCount: 1,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] },
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/fetchPanch',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *4],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
        'content-type': [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8' ],
        'user-agent': [ 'User-Agent', 'axios/0.21.0' ],
        'content-length': [ 'Content-Length', 79 ],
        host: [ 'Host', 'localhost:3000' ]
      }
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/api/fetchPanch',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am not able to test my API. Can somebody please help me with this problem I am having, please help.

Thanks in advance,
Japroz Saini

Comment: Are you using SSL? Can't seem to find how you have configured OpenSSL in index.js

Answer (score 1):

Hear is the reason why your getting that in the terminal:**Your using axios the same way as the javascript built-in `fetch` API**

With the fetch API you do something like this

```
fetch('http://url',params,body).then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>res).catch(err=>...)
```

In the first chaining `then` i did `res.json()` and in the second one that where i access the actual data.

But in `axios` not need to do `res=res.json()` because you can directly access data in the first `then` like this :

```
 axios.post('http://url',body).then(res=>res.data).catch(err=>...)
```

The `data` sent by the server is in the `data attribute` of the `res object`

Answer (score -2):

You need to require http if you are making any kind of get/post request.
`const http = require('http')`
Add this to your code and also replace https with http wherever used.